# Exercise in SQL with complex subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I'm trying to do a query in SQL. The database is the one of IMBD one. This is the form:

[image]

So, I need the actors/actress from the film Pulp Fiction(id=2175869) that never acted jointly in no other film with another actor / actress of Pulp Fiction.

It should be something like:

```
SELECT person_id FROM cast_info WHERE movie_id = 2175869 AND
person_id NOT IN (SELECT )
```

But I can't figure it out how to do the second part.

Comment: @Sami I'm not pretty sure about it. Are you refering to the same as @Harshil?

Comment: Yes, he is referring to same question as mine

Comment: Okey, thanks, I'm learning it right now

Comment: I am unable to find a table that give me list of all movies (movie_id) for a person_id(actor/actress). Please help me out here.

Comment: @Harshil There is not one. Title contains the info of every movie. You can relate the two tables using title.id = cast_info.person_id

Comment: ok. Thank you. Let me try then

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela how will you match like this title.id = cast_info.person_id ? both are different na?

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar Exactly. Both looks different.

Comment: @Harshil @ VijayaVigneshKumar that's true. It's title.id = cast_info.movie_id. I was mistaken, sorry...

Comment: Ok thanks @Jaime and Harshil.. let me try

Comment: Try this @JaimeAlcántaraArnela ** select person_id form person_info where person_id in ( select person_id from cast_info where movie_id in ( select id from title where id = 2175869)) **

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar Trying, it will take time, I'll inform you when it ends

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Also [put everything you can as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3404097) even if you supplement with images/links--here, that's (*minimal necessary*) DDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query used later as sub-query, returning movies other than Pulp Fiction where more than one actor of Pulp Fiction played in them

```
SELECT movie_id
FROM cast_info
WHERE
    movie_id <> 2175869 AND
    person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM cast_info WHERE movie_id = 2175869)
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Now get persons playing in Pulp Fiction who never played in such a movie

```
SELECT person_id
FROM cast_info
WHERE
    movie_id = 2175869 AND
    person_id NOT IN (
        SELECT person_id FROM cast_info WHERE movie_id IN (
            SELECT movie_id
            FROM cast_info
            WHERE
                movie_id <> 2175869 AND
                person_id IN (SELECT person_id FROM cast_info WHERE movie_id = 2175869)
            GROUP BY movie_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
    )
```

Note: I am assuming that one actor can be casted only once per movie. If the same actor can be casted for different roles in the same movie, then replace `COUNT(*)` by `COUNT(DISTINCT person_id)`.

Comment: Checking, it's a very big database so it will take time but it's running right know, I'll post the result sooner or later. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to see all actors from pulp fiction:

```
SELECT person_id  as pulp_actor_id
FROM cast_info
WHERE movie_id = 2175869
```

Then you need to find all the actor duos:

```
SELECT c1.person_id as actor1_id
       c2.person_id as actor2_id
FROM cast_info c1
JOIN cast_info c2
  ON c1.person_id < c2.person_id
WHERE c1.movie_id = 2175869
  AND c2.movie_id = 2175869;
```

Find all the movies where duo act together beside pulp fiction.

```
SELECT actor1_id, actor2_id, actor1_movies.movie_id
FROM (SELECT c1.person_id as actor1_id
             c2.person_id as actor2_id
      FROM cast_info c1
      JOIN cast_info c2
        ON c1.person_id < c2.person_id
      WHERE c1.movie_id = 2175869
        AND c2.movie_id = 2175869) as duos
JOIN cast_info as actor1_movies
  ON duos.actor1_id = actor1_movies.person_id
 AND actor1.movie_id <> 2175869
LEFT JOIN cast_info actor2_movies
  ON duos.actor2_id = actor2_movies.person_id
 AND actor1_movies.movie_id = actor2_movies.movie_id
WHERE actor2.movie_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Now get all the actors from pulp fiction not in the last result

```
SELECT person_id as pulp_actor_id
FROM cast_info c
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT actor1_id, actor2_id, actor1_movies.movie_id
            FROM (SELECT c1.person_id as actor1_id
                         c2.person_id as actor2_id
                  FROM cast_info c1
                  JOIN cast_info c2
                    ON c1.person_id < c2.person_id
                  WHERE c1.movie_id = 2175869
                    AND c2.movie_id = 2175869) as duos
            JOIN cast_info as actor1_movies
              ON duos.actor1_id = actor1_movies.person_id
             AND actor1.movie_id <> 2175869
            LEFT JOIN cast_info actor2_movies
              ON duos.actor2_id = actor2_movies.person_id
             AND actor1_movies.movie_id = actor2_movies.movie_id
            WHERE actor2.movie_id IS NOT NULL;
            WHERE movie_id = 2175869 ) as duos
  ON c.person_id IN ( actor1_id, actor2_id )
WHERE duos.movie_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it but it will take time, I'll post you the results.

Comment: Hola Jaime, Check Olver answer, is simpler than mine.

Comment: Muy honesto por tu parte Juan Carlos, gracias, voy a ello